# Next Js style according to browser

Tags: css, facebook, next.js, vercel

When i open my website in facebook or linkedin, the color of the background change to a strange flashy green. Only in those webviews.

When i open it in other app like twitter or instagram, i have the correct linear-gradient background defined in my global css file.

[bug description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8y8e.jpg)

here is my global.css

I have tried to add separate class to define the gradient and fix the problem.

````
:root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 40, 219, 20;
    --background-end-rgb: 31, 108, 63;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
        --background-start-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
        --background-end-rgb: 31, 108, 63;
    }
}

body {
    color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
    background-color: rgb(
        var(--background-start-rgb)
    ); /* Couleur d'arrière-plan par défaut */
}

.gradient-background {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            transparent,
            rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
        )
        rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}```

`<html lang="en">
            <body>
                <div className="gradient-background">{children}</div>
            </body>
        </html>`
````

Answer (score 0):

something similar happened to me recently but I don't know if you're facing the exact same problem.

This could be because the apps with webviews where you're not getting the result you want all have have some dark setting (hence obeying to the condition <prefers-color-scheme: dark>).

Try setting both the block with <:root> and <@media->:root> to the same values (for the background that you desire) and test to see.